# Issues with calculating MAE and RMSE for a ARIMA model

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, forecasting, arima

I'm currently building a forecast model that measures gambling dollars against time. Based on what I have so far, my forecast values looks to be fairly accurate but I want to confirm it by measuring couple metrics such as MSE, MAE, RMSE.

In cell[65] , my MSE/RMSE is shown as NaN. I believe the problem might be within the data itself but I can't pinpoint the actual issue.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Here's the [link](https://github.com/swc0307/Sports-Betting/blob/master/ARIMA%20Nevada.ipynb) to show what I have so far.

Comment: df_truth = df.iloc['start_date': 'end data', :]

Comment: when i changed it to `df_truth = df.iloc['2014-01-01':'2019-09-01',:]`, i get this error: TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>...

I used .loc instead and that gave me the same NaN outcome

Comment: could you print df.loc['2014-01-01':'2019-09-01',:]? in the notebook and git push

Comment: this is the output from df.loc: https://imgur.com/a/fh4lBDn

Comment: i just wanted to see print(df.loc['2014-01-01':'2019-09-01',:])

Comment: the data looks to be correct: https://imgur.com/a/jR5CWa6

Comment: Does df_truth  = df.loc['2014-01-01':'2019-09-01','SB Handle'] work? if that doesn't I would suggest you to convert pandas series to numpy arrays .Cause it looks fine

Comment: Yes that helped! Not the result that I was hoping for but thanks for your tip!

Comment: So what solved it?

Comment: changing `df_truth = df.iloc['2014-01-01':'2019-09-01',:]` to `df_truth = df.loc['2014-01-01':'2019-09-01','SB Handle']`